# Is Angular 2 change detection mechanism synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: angular

I read an excellent article about [Angular 2 change detection mechanism](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/).

But I can't still fully understand if it is synchronous or asynchronous. Which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `(click)="foo()"`, angular translates this into something like:

```
addEventListener('click', ($event) => {
  component.foo();
  detectChanges();
});
```

Likewise, if you do `setTimeout(foo)`, angular rewrites this to:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  foo();
  detectChanges();
}
```

by monkey patching setTimeout().

That is, change detection happens right after the event listener has executed, before control is returned to the browser, or any other javascript code is executed. The following flame graph, taken in chrome's developer tool's performance tab, proves this:

[image: change detection is synchronous]

That is, change detection is part of the event listener the browser sees. If that listener is invoked synchronously, so is change detection.

Answer (score 0):

As with all things javascript in the browser.  The digest cycle is async.